# Error while passing variable as function to object. in Python 3.7.0pyt

Tags: python, python-3.x

While practicing in Python, i was trying to pass a variable to the object of class, and that variable is having name of the function of class, i got a error, i am not getting Following error...

```
class testing():
    def __init__(self, name):
        print('This is From INIT of testing calss...')
        self.name = name

    def good(self):
        print('Hello {} Good things of the day'.format(self.name))

    def bad(self):
        print('Hello {} Bad things of the day'.format(self.name))

ts = testing('Pranit')
ch = str(input('Enter choice : good or bad :'))
ts.ch()

output error

C:\Users\pranit>python "C:\Users\pranit\Music\Python Only\FunPractice.py"
This is From INIT of testing calss...
Enter choice : good or bad :good
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pranit\Music\Python Only\FunPractice.py", line 15, in <module>
    ts.ch()
AttributeError: 'testing' object has no attribute 'ch'

C:\Users\pranit>
```

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, the solution is `getattr(obj, name[, default=None)`:

```
ts = testing('Pranit')
ch = input('Enter choice : good or bad :')
method = getattr(ts, ch, None)
if method:
    method()
```

but in this case (selecting a function or method based on user inputs) it's better (for safety reasons) to explicitely maps allowed functions/methods either in the client code:

```
ts = testing('Pranit')
allowed = {"good": ts.good, "bad": ts.bad}
ch = input('Enter choice : good or bad :')
method = allowed.get(ch, None)
if method:
    method()
```

or directly in the class (depending on who should be responsible for knowing which methods are allowed here):

```
# XXX Python naming conventions: class names should be CamelCased
class Testing():
    def __init__(self, name):
        print('This is From INIT of testing calss...')
        self.name = name

    def good(self):
        print('Hello {} Good things of the day'.format(self.name))

    def bad(self):
        print('Hello {} Bad things of the day'.format(self.name))

    ALLOWED = {"good": good, "bad": bad}

    def handle(self, choice):
       if choice not in self.ALLOWED:
           raise ValueError("'%s' is not a valid choice" % choice)
       return self.ALLOWED[choice][self]
```